# "Slicing" and "Replacing" a string for homework

Tags: python

I am stuck on a problem for my class. The pic of the problem is down below. I'm trying to convert this string "abcd efgh ijkl" to this "AbCd eFgH IjKl" using ordinal function/values to capitalize even index numbers.

This is what I got so far:

```
def mock(string):
    index = 0
    for i in string:
        if string.find(i, index) % 2 == 0:
            string.replace(i,(chr(ord(i) - 32)))
        index = string.find(i) + 1
    return string

print(mock("abcd efgh ijkl"))
```

Any help is appreciated.

[Pic of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8gNX.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) returns string, but you aren't assigning the return value to anything. Also you need to handle spaces correctly (thanks @JacobStrauss for further simplification!)

```
def mock(string):
    for i in string:
        if i != ' ' and string.find(i) % 2 == 0:
            string = string.replace(i, (chr(ord(i) - 32)))
    return string

print(mock("abcd efgh ijkl"))
```

Prints:

```
AbCd eFgH IjKl
```

Comment: Andrej....thank you so much! I've been stuck on this problem for days!!!

Comment: @TomC If this answer satisfies your question, please mark it as accepted. By doing that you can help others to find the solution faster.

Comment: your function will find multiple occurrence of a character and capitalize it.  add 'a' multiple times and it will be capitalized for every occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

All credit to Andrej Kesely for providing a solution, but I just wanted to improve on it slightly. Since you are already iterating over a string, and the .find() method returns an index position, you do not need to keep track of the index! I've tested the code below and it works just as well.

```
def mock(string):
    for i in string:
        if i != ' ' and string.find(i) % 2 == 0:
            string = string.replace(i, (chr(ord(i) - 32)))
    return string
```

The above returns "AbCd eFgH IjKl"

Answer (score -1):

use a for loop and a upper the string by index character

```
def capitalize(string):
    result=""
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if i%2==0:
            result+=string[i].upper()
        else:
            result+=string[i]
    return result

string="abcd efgaah ijklaaa"
print(capitalize(string))
```

output:

```
AbCd eFgAaH IjKlAaA
```

Comment: this is a more correct code base because the ending aaa is capitalized correctly according to odd and even index, whereas, the previous code samples do not.